# First order differential equation to standard form conversion

Tags: recurrence-relations

I need to convert the following differential equation to standard form.

$$ T_n = 2 T_{n-1}+1 $$
(not quite sure how to really format it properly)

I was thinking it is

$$ T_n - 2T_{n-1} - 1$$

If I'm incorrect (or correct) can I please have somebody just explain briefly about the decreasing order. I'm just confused about the whole number, in this case the number 1, I'm not quite sure if it's bigger or smaller than the others.

Answer (score 0):

If we set $T_n = A_n-1$ then we have $ A_n  = 2 A_{n-1} $, hence $A_n = 2^n A_0$ and $T_n = 2^n(T_0+1)-1.$

Comment: That has confused me a fair bit. I'm quite new to all this and I don't quite understand. does this mean that the recurrence relation is non-homogenous?

Comment: @user242116: did you think that $f'(x)-2f(x)=1$ is a homogeneous ODE?